# Firestore webpage shows wrong data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a small problem that is driveing me crazy.
It seems that the Firestore Webpage is not showing my Database correctly.
If i add data via flutter it shows up immediately. And if i delete it again via code it dissapears like it should.
But if i delete in inside the Browser. It disapears but i can still access it via code.
The same thing applies to editing via the Browser. It changes visually but accessing via code i get the old Value. I thought i might be a delay so I waited until the next Day, but the web View and the code Values where still different.
Is this a Bug ?

```
      .collection(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .doc("SavedChain")
      .snapshots()
      .first;
```

This is how i access the data.

[This is how i delete it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvGMZ.png)

After deleting it, it disapears like it should. But i can still access it with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `snapshots().first` gives you the cached value for the document. If that is the case, the solution is to use `get()` instead of those two calls:

```
  .collection(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
  .doc("SavedChain")
  .get();
```